# Angular container application with any child applications

Tags: angular, containers

I worked for 4 years with angular 1. In these years i developed a main project which works as a kind of application container. It handles basic functions like main navigation template, routing, authentication, user module loading, password reset, etc...

Thanks to this schema i can develop only views and controller of any single project in separate folders (and git repos).

So my main container everytime knows (thanks to a config file) which application has to load by including at runtime all the files of the application in its specific folder on the web server.

I'm very new to angular 2 and I would like to know if is there a use case similar to mine.
Could you help me please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can lazy load Angular 2+ modules, I think that would fit what you are looking for, check it out here https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: Please be more specific of what use case you are looking for. The question you have asked is very broad. You cant just ask for a entire project code in here. If you are new to angular start with small apps. You can refer https://github.com/shashankvivek/angular4 and follow .

Comment: I succesfully used lazy loading feature...now I have another question: is it possible to lazy load modules which are outside app folder? This is for my project separation. Thanks in advance